# 7Zip extract from command line creates subfolders

Tags: 7-zip

I have a command line I'm issuing to 7Zip using the `e` (extract) command, which should, in theory disregard the full paths.

So I start with this:

[image: 7zipfile]

However, on issuing this command:

`C:\Program Files\7-Zip>7z.exe e C:\Temp\BFJv124i13-35540519-293262.zip -aos -oC:\Temp\Unzipped\*.xml -r`

The zip file is extracting into the unzip folder like this:

[image: Incorrect extract to subfolder]

I want the files to unzip directly under `\Unzipped`.

I can do this from the GUI:

[image: Gui settings]

and it gives me the correct extraction:

[image: Desired output]

What am I doing wrong in my command line?

Comment: And what happens if you leave `*.xml -r` completely out of the command?

Answer (score 0):

Your command should look like this.

```
C:\Program Files\7-Zip>7z.exe e C:\Temp\BFJv124i13-35540519-293262.zip -aos -oC:\Temp\Unzipped *.xml -r
```

The -o flag is used to specify the output folder; however, in your command, you are using a wildcard for the file name; this makes 7-Zip create a subfolder with the name of the XML file.

Comment: Ahhh, thank you. User error and I'm an idiot. That works perfectly.